# R group_by multiple conditionnal aggregation functions dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr, summarize

I am searching to compute functions on a group conditionnaly. `agg_name` describes functions to evaluate, this vector can be length 1 to N. Here N = 5 and all possibilities are knew but I would prefer something general.

```
agg_name <- c("Sum = sum(val)", "Mean = mean(val)")

df <- data.frame(dateDay = Sys.Date()-rep(0:2, each = 3), val = 1:9)
```

Attempt so far :

```
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(dateDay) %>% 
  summarise(eval(paste(agg_name, collapse = ",")))
```

Expected output :

```
     dateDay Sum Mean
1 2019-09-04   6    2
2 2019-09-03   15   5
3 2019-09-02   24   8
```

An other column would have been created if `agg_name` contains `Max = max(val)`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
agg_name <- c(Sum = sum, Mean = mean)

df %>% 
 group_by(dateDay) %>% 
 summarise_all(agg_name)

  dateDay      Sum  Mean
  <date>     <int> <dbl>
1 2019-09-02    24     8
2 2019-09-03    15     5
3 2019-09-04     6     2
```

Comment: Exactly what I need, thank you very much. I knew my trials were to complicated for what I want.